# Find out Robot Coordinate using odometer data

Tags: mobile-robot, inverse-kinematics, odometry

I have a data set name Robot_odometery which consist of 3 field namely, Time(s),Forward velocity(m/s) and angular velocity(rad/s). I taken this dataset from http://asrl.utias.utoronto.ca/datasets/mrclam/index.html website. I want to calculate x,y,theta coordinate using this odometer dataset. As per the conversion from rectangular co-ordinate to polar ones I came to know two formula to calculate x and y. `x=rcos(theta)` and `y=rsin(theta)`. I want to know that is that right approach to find out the Robot  coordinate (x,y). or there is any thing else that can be used to find Robot coordinate from odometer data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hence the orientation and position are the integrals of the angular ($\dot{\theta}$) and forward velocity ($v$) (in robot frame) respectively. So you have everything you need to calculate your pose.

Now, the problem is that you misinterpret the tree states you have. $x$,$y$ represent the x and y position on a euclidean plane. $\theta$ is the heading of the robot and not the polar angle corresponding to polar coordinates. I.e. it is the angle the robot is turned around the z-axis at the position (x,y).

Therefore, if you integrate the angular velocity over time you get the orientation - i.e. theta - and with the heading you can integrate the forward velocity to determine the coordinates x and y.

Something like that:
$$
\theta_k = \dot{\theta}_{k-1} \cdot \Delta t + \theta_{k-1} \\
x_k = v_k \cdot \Delta t \cdot cos(\theta_k) + x_{k-1} \\
y_k = v_k \cdot \Delta t \cdot sin(\theta_k) + y_{k-1} 
$$

Comment: Thank you. Do you follow the dataset that given by http://asrl.utias.utoronto.ca/datasets/mrclam/index.html ?? Actually I am working on this data set. This is very kind of you if you take a look on this data set.What is Δt? What is xk−1(is that initial position of a Robot)?

Comment: $k$ is an integer number identifying one particular time step. Therefore, $x_{k-1}$ means the $x$ position one time step before.If $k=0$, $x_k$ is the initial position and $x_{k-1}$ is assumed to be 0.  However, $\Delta t$ means the time difference between two consecutive, discrete time steps. E.g. $\Delta t = t_{k} - t_{k-1} $.

Comment: Thank you. I figure it out. After computing this value this value is not same as the Robot Groundtruth value which take using Gps. Is the calculating values from odometer data and groundtruth value will be same for a particular Robot?

Comment: https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/15822/landmark-identification-using-range-and-bearning   please have look on this question.

Comment: Ideally speaking, YES. But it depens how good your estimation is. In order to get an estimate you can measure the root mean square error between your estimation and the ground truth. This gives you an idea about how wrong you are.

Comment: Sir, But there is a huge differences. In robot ground truth data it was start from 3.5467 then the value is decreased with changing time. Then it came to zero then the values goes to negative and then from negative it again goes up and at last came to 3.34567 like that. But in measured value the value start from 0.675432 like that then increase upto 3.09756,then decrease and came to negative values ,afterthat change to positive and goes up with end value 323.0978 like that. So there is a huge difference. Can you tell me what goes wrong?

Comment: One more thing the point that I got it is in local frame but the point that describe in Robot ground truth table are in global frame. So how could I transform local frame point to global frame points?